# Can't use pygame.init

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, init

I installed pygame using:
`pip3 install pygame`

I'm unable to do any work and get failed request error message.

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 2.1.0 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  105
  Current serial number in output stream:  106
```

I read the pygame doumentation --> initialization, and got the same message

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 2.1.0 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> pygame.init()
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  105
  Current serial number in output stream:  106
```

when I run this code in jupyter notebook the kernel shuts down/dies.

Comment: Might be a problem with your graphics card driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this problem because of some depedencies not installed by using pip/pip3.
Solved this problem simply by installing pygame using package manager which installed the packages required to make pygame work with my default graphics card.

However if you use NV gpu, you should be good to go regardless of how you istalled the package.

Otherwise use:

`sudo apt install python3-pygame`